# How to insert an ID number that gets assigned to all rows in second column

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table that consists of two columns i.e. [Cost Center] and [EmployeeID]. There are 399 Cost Centers and all of them have EmployeeIDs. The problem I am facing is that I need to insert a new EmployeeID that gets assigned to all the Cost Centers. 
So some how it has to iterate through all the existing Cost Centers and insert the New ID for all of them.

All tips and ideas on how to solve the problem are very much appreciated

This is the desired result
Example table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t (costcenter, employeeid)
    select distinct costcenter, 123
    from t;
```

If you have a separate table of cost centers, then you can use that:

```
insert into t (costcenter, employeeid)
    select costcenter, 123
    from costcenters;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you for you reply.
When I try do do this I get this error:
"failed because it contains a derived or constant field". I assume this occur because the table is a view. Is it possible to do the same insert statement on the view or should i do it on the original table ?

Comment: @Rubrix . . . You should insert into the original table.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon !